# PHP $_FILES doesn't load properly

Tags: php, javascript, html, upload

I wish I could just give you a link but last time they blamed it all on me so here is the javascript code:

```
function Multifile(list){
    this.id=0;
    this.list=list;

    this.createNew=function(element){
        element.name='file[]';
        element.multiFile=this;

        element.onchange=function(){
            var newElement=document.createElement('input');
            newElement.type='file';
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement,this);
            this.multiFile.createNew(newElement);
            this.multiFile.addList(this);
            this.style.position='absolute';
            this.style.left='-1000px';
        };
    };

    this.addList=function(element){
        var newRow=document.createElement('div');
        var newButton=document.createElement('input');

        newButton.type='button';
        newButton.value='delete';
        newRow.element=element;

        newButton.onclick=function(){
            this.parentNode.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.element);
            this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
            return false; //safari thing
        };

        newRow.innerHTML=element.value;
        newRow.appendChild(newButton);
        this.list.appendChild(newRow);
    };
};

var multifile=new Multifile(document.getElementById('fList'));
multifile.createNew(document.getElementById('file'));
```

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="upload" action="uploadPost.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
            <input id="file" type="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
        </form>
        <div id="fList">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptcode.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My PHP Script:
    ';
        echo $_FILES['file']['name'][1](http://lookaroundyou.net/uploads/upload.php);
    ?>

and in the end here is my question:

after choosing 2 files it never wants to print array member [0]
except when i delete second file it gives it array member value of 1 to the first element that initially had array member value of [0]

[HERE](http://lookaroundyou.net/uploads/upload.php) is the link to see what is my story about

Comment: What does `var_dump( $_FILES )` give?

Comment: Can you show the results of `var_dump($_FILES);` run in the upload script?

Comment: array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(6) "shadow" [2]=> string(5) "group" } ["type"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream" [2]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(14) "/tmp/php3NXUyj" [2]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpbBVhSj" } ["error"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(916) } } } 
shadow

Comment: foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $file) {
            echo $file;
        } /*this stuff works, but why not previous one it is still a mystery to me */

Comment: SOLVED IT myself. it is because insertBefore() puts new 'empty' input element on the first[0] place every time new file is chosen. thank you people!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a typo.

```
 enctype="multipart/formdata"
```

needs to be

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```